# UIView / UIControl ignoring frame rect. Always fullscreen

Tags: ios, uiview, swift2

I am trying to build custom components in Swift 2.2, and obviously missing something essential.  My views ignore the frame rect.

In the containing view, I add the view programmatically like this:

```
let arrowControl = ArrowControl(frame: CGRect(x: 100 , y: 100, width: 300, height: 300))
self.view.addSubview(arrowControl)
```

In fact, even if I programmatically add a UIView or UIControl, without subclassing it - then the view ignores the frame rect, and occupies the entire screen.

Here are the essential parts of my custom view:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}


override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    renderComponent(frame)
}
```

EDIT>>>>

If I change my example, and remove renderComponent, I still get the same problem.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.clipsToBounds = true
   backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
 // renderComponent(self.frame)
}
```

Or even doing the following ignores the frame rect, and gives me a full screen block of colour:

```
let test = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100 , y: 100, width: 300, height: 300))
test.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.view.addSubview(test)
```

Comment: what is your renderComponent method doing? or you can try to set clipTobounds or markToBound property to true to see if it helps.

Comment: If I change my example, and remove renderComponent, I still get the same problem.  See edit in above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh!  I worked it out.  It turns out it was my own fault, as I'd implemented the following in the containing view:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  for view in self.view.subviews {
      view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
  }
}
```